# Javascript/JQuery iterate through table rows and cells and output an attr of checked checkboxes to console

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have the following code, which should go through each table row and dump my array which is declared in an earlier segment of javascript. Then if the checkbox is checked, and it has an attr of "changed=yes" then it should be pushed onto the array and the value should be outputted in console as well as the "path" attribute which should be outputted as a variable that can be overwritten every time the function finds a new checkbox that is checked and changed. So what is wrong with my code? These functions are contained in a function that is called when the user clicks submit on the form.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hU89p/392/

```
        $('#myTable1 tr').each(function(){
        myArray = [];
                    $.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked").closest("td").siblings("td"),
                    function () {
                    if($(this).data("changed") == 'yes'){
                        myArray.push($(this).attr('checkboxtype'));
                        filepath = $(this).attr('path');
                        console.log(myArray);
                        console.log(filepath);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Can you provide us the HTML part of it?

Comment: Sure, I will make a jsfiddle

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hU89p/392/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hU89p/394/) :

Keep it simple :

```
$('#myTable1 tr').each(function() {
       var columns = $(this).find('td');

       columns.each(function() {
           var box = $(this).find('input:checkbox');

           if(box.is(":checked") && box.attr("changed") == 'yes')
           {
                myArray.push(box.attr('checkboxtype'));
                filepath = box.attr('path');                            
            }
        });
    });
         console.log(myArray);
  });
```

Comment: That works, but the array should clear every time it reaches a new row and should be outputted. However, if the console.log(myArray) is placed within the if statement it spams the console. Why is it spamming the console if i put console.log(myArray) within the if statement?

Comment: What do u want to show...u can push to array and log it in the console? Spamming the console because its inside two `each` loops ( one for rows and other for columns)

Comment: Ah I see, is there any other way to do it without each loops? Eventually i will be passing an array using JSON or AJAX every time a box is checked and changed in a row to another php form, I don't want the results to accumulate in an array unless that is the only way it will work.

Comment: Okay, You can attach an event handler to your checkbox click then, and execute ajax on check ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").closest("td").siblings("td").each()`.

See the difference between [`$().each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Comment: No errors :/, but the other solution seems to work except that it spams my console instead of say showing me the results of two changed checkboxes, it will show me that but 20+ times

Answer (score 0):

```
try this :-

     $('#myTable1 tr').each(function () {
                myArray = [];
                $(this).find("td input:checkbox").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).attr("changed") == 'yes') {
                        myArray.push($(this).attr('checkboxtype'));
                        filepath = $(this).attr('path');
                        console.log(myArray);
                        console.log(filepath);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: This is more or less what I was looking for, the only problem is that my console is getting spammed beyond what I should be seeing.